# confirmation box with just yes button

Tags: jquery, confirmbutton

I have a form and when i click submit i want to display a box saying thank you and some information.
Now I just want the box to show OK. So i really dont need a confirmation box but something similar with just an OK button. Can i modify my existing code to achieve it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 

    $('form.new').submit(function(){ 

            if (!confirm('Thank you')) { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    }); 

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of confirm use alert().  It only has an ok button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alert instead of a confirm box with just an ok button in it..and it can perform any action after ok is pressed..

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Leje6/)

```
if (!alert('Thank you')) {
          alert('ok clicked');
          return false;  
 }
```

You can call any javascript function before returning false...